# How can I get a slices new index after a goroutine channel has mutated the slice?

Tags: go

I'm wondering how I can get an elements new index in a slice, I have a function that gets applications from a database, and queries for certain ones (for filtering) but when I query for ones and I get ones I don't need, I'm trying to remove them from the slice so that only the wanted ones make it to the view. It's working but I'm having a problem with the index's in the goroutines are the older index's so when it trys to remove the element from the slice it panics: Anyways here is my code:

```
// ListApplications will list the applications
func ListApplications(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    session := common.Sesh(r)
    urlParse, err := url.ParseRequestURI(r.RequestURI)
    vals := urlParse.Query()

    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    if lvl, ok := session.Values["user_level"]; !ok || lvl.(int) < 3 {
        http.Redirect(w, r, "/", 401)
        return
    }

    db := common.Db()

    type UserResp struct {
        Action string
        I      int
        User   common.User
    }
    apps := []common.Application{}
    resp := make(chan UserResp)
    db.Order("accepted asc").Order("created_at asc").Find(&apps)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i, app := range apps {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(i int, app common.Application) {
            user := common.User{}
            if vals.Get("class") != "" {
                db.Preload("Characters", "character_class = ?", vals.Get("class")).Model(&app).Related(&user)
                if len(user.Characters) == 0 {
                    resp <- UserResp{"remove", i, user}
                } else {
                    resp <- UserResp{"add", i, user}
                }
                wg.Done()
                return
            }

            db.Preload("Characters").Model(&app).Related(&user)
            log.Println(user)
            resp <- UserResp{"add", i, user}
            wg.Done()
        }(i, app)
    }

    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(resp)
    }()

    for user := range resp {
        switch user.Action {
        case "add":
            apps[user.I].User = user.User
        case "remove":
        log.Println(len(apps), user.I)
            apps = append(apps[:user.I], apps[user.I+1:]...)
        }
    }

    common.View(w, r, "/application/list", &struct {
        Title string
        Apps  []common.Application
    }{"Viewing Applications", apps})
}
```

The `for user := range resp` is where I'm trying to delete under the `"remove"` action. But like I said, the index getting passed through on the channel is out dated sometimes so how can I maintain a persistent index in my goroutines

Answer (score 2):

Don't `range` over a slice if you want to remove elements from it.

Instead, loop over the slice by index:

```
// Removes 2 from slice.
slice := []int{1,2,3}
for i := 0; i < len(slice); i++ {
    if slice[i] == 2 {
        slice = append(slice[:i], slice[i+1:]...)
        i--
    }
}
fmt.Println(slice) // [1 3]
```

The point is bringing the index cursor back by one (so it won't go forward) after you've removed the current element.

Comment: Do I need to compare against the value to make it work properly? Because my Application struct cannot be compared to other things because it has slice fields in it and what not

Comment: @Datsik Nope, you can keep your switch statement. Just loop by index instead of `range` and decrement the index by one after you've removed an element.